# Invalid syntax zipfile(apkAbsPath) in line 202 ninjadroid.py

Tags: android, python

I cloned ninjadroid from https://github.com/rovellipaolo/NinjaDroid recently and followed the instructions for decompiling apk files. As instructed I have installed android sdk and python, but when I tried running the command in my command prompt (`python ninjadroid.py -t myPackage.apk`), it throws the below error

```
File "ninjadroid.py", line 202
    with ZipFile(apkAbsPath) as z:
```

Answer (score 0):

Mmm... that's strange.

Is 'myPackage.apk' an existing file (in your computer)? Is it a real APK package? From the error, I would say you are trying to reverse a non-APK file.

Unfortunately the "is-APK" check in the current, available version is a lazy check - done pretty badly. I completely reimplemented it in the new version I am working on.

### UPDATE

With the newest NinjaDroid version (i.e. 2.0):

```
$ python ninjadroid.py this_is_a_non_existing_file
  >> NinjaDroid: [ERROR] The target file (i.e. 'this_is_a_non_existing_file') must be an existing, readable file!

$ touch this_is_an_existing_file_but_not_an_apk_package.txt
$ python ninjadroid.py this_is_an_existing_file_but_not_an_apk_package.txt
  >> NinjaDroid: [ERROR] The target file (i.e. 'this_is_an_existing_file_but_not_an_apk_package.txt') must be an APK package!

$ python ninjadroid.py test/data/Example.apk
{
    "app_name": "Example",
    ...
}
```